# How to delete one specific characters from a word within a file based on a condition

Tags: bash, files, text

How can I delete one or more specific characters of some words within a file that respect one condition like in the example:

The condition here its that the script will delete all the **a** characters of every even length word.

file content before:

```
abad a_12
asf     aga 3
```

file content after:

```
bd _12
asf     aga 3
```

I have tried with **sed** but i dont know how can i put the condition instead of **g**:

```
sed 's/a//g'
```

Comment: Thank you a lot man!

Comment: @bac0n that will replace all the **a**s on any line that contains a 4-letter "word" I think? Although that gives the desired output for the OP's example (and may indeed be what they want) it's not the same as "all the **a** characters of every even length word"

Comment: here sorry ... better delete the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward in awk, assuming a "word" is a whitespace-delimited field:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if( !(length($i)%2) ) gsub("a","",$i)}} 1'
```

ex.:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if( !(length($i)%2) ) gsub("a","",$i)}} 1' file
bd _12
asf     aga 3
```

Comment: {for(i=1;i<=file;i++){if( !(length($i)%2) ) gsub("a","",$i)}} 1: command not found     and i changed NF and file to my file name

Comment: NF should be as it was, the input file is placed at the end